# Question about constant product AMM swap function

Tags: uniswap, defi

My understanding is that there are two main flows when one wants to swap within a constant product AMM LP:

1. Trader transfers a certain amount of Token X into the LP
2. An equivalent of Token Y is transferred to Trader

Assuming that both Token X and Token Y are ERC-20 compliant, are there any issues if I use transfer() for both Flow 1 and Flow 2? Or, should I actually be using transferFrom() instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use transferFrom(). I'll attempt to give an explanation below, but it would also be helpful to look at the Uniswap code. Here's a link to the UniswapV2 Router swap functions: https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/0335e8f7e1bd1e8d8329fd300aea2ef2f36dd19f/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L224

If a user calls transfer() to send tokens to the LP, it has only interacted with the ERC20 token contract to decrement their own token balance and increment the balance of the LP address. The LP smart contract wouldn't be called and has no place to execute the code to calculate how many token Y should be sent to the user and then do so.

Instead the user should call approve() on the ERC20 token contract to allow the LP (or the AMM router) to call transferFrom() with their tokens. Then the user can call the swap function which will handle the transfer in, the price calculation and the transfer out.

There are always other ways to write code, but this way is probably the most straight-forward.